# resetting the data in a radio button

Tags: java, android

I have 2 radio buttons on my initial page to choose a gender. Depending on boy or girl this then sets `gender` to 1 or 2. I have a reset button to go back to the main screen and in this button I have used, `rg.setSelected(false)` to reset the radio button, but for some reason even though I have also set `gender` back to 0 when clicking reset. When I choose the opposite sex radio button the gender int stays as the one that was first selected? I have done a Log to ensure `gender` reverts back to 0 on pressing reset which it does.

I am also wanting to reset the name, so when pressing the reset button I have done `reader = ""` but again using a Log, the name always remains as the first one that was input.

Can anyone help with how I get these to display the new values when entering them again without having to close the app?

Edited with code,

// code to get which radio button is selected,

```
 public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.boyButton) {
        gender = 1;

    } else if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.girlButton){
        gender = 2;
    }
}
```

//code to reset,

```
 public void reset(View view) {


    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    gender = 0;
    reader = "";
    rg.clearCheck();
    Log.i("Gender", Integer.toString(gender));
    Log.i("name", reader);
}
```

(I changed the code to clear the checkbox to `rg.clearCheck()` and that now seems to clear it, `gender` changes to 0 but then when I select a new gender and enter `gender` stays at 0 now.

It's like the second time I enter the details it's not being picked up and the code for the enter button isn't running

//code for enter button

```
public void enterName(View view) {

    reader =  nameText1.getText().toString();

    setContentView(R.layout.melvin);
    melvinSpeaks1 = findViewById(R.id.melvinSpeak1);
    melvinText1 = findViewById(R.id.melvinText1);
    rudolphSpeaks1 = findViewById(R.id.rudolphSpeak1);
    rudolphText1 = findViewById(R.id.rudolphText1);
    melvin1 = findViewById(R.id.melvinBubble);
    rudolph1 = findViewById(R.id.rudolphBubble);
    reset = findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    melvinText1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rudolphText1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rudolph1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    melvin1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.i("Gender", Integer.toString(gender));
    Log.i("name", reader)

}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please show some code. RadioGroup also has the method `clearCheck()` which deselects all RadioButtons under it.

Comment: Have added some code to my original post. I changed to rg.clearChecked() which seemed to clear it, but when I then reselect a radio button and enter, it doesn't seem to pick it up and the gender value stays at 0 now instead of being 1 or 2 depending on which sex was chosen.

Comment: You should also be using a [RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) and not manually-specified click methods.

Comment: In place of this??
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.boyButton) {
        gender = 1;

    } else if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.girlButton){
        gender = 2;
    }
}

Thanks

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming you have that method set in `onClick` in your XML. Remove all that and use the proper listener.

Comment: I have managed to get it to change the gender one the first time I press reset. But then it stick on that gender! I also can't get the name to change still. I have set the editText.setText().clear()....this clears the text but then when I type another name into it it remains empty. the whole project is here,

https://github.com/Dannyj1984/EmilyhelpsMelvin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/emilyhelpsmelvin/MainActivity.java

I still haven't been able to get the checkedchangedlistener to work so I am still using onRadioButtonClicked.

Thanks for any help